AttachVolume.Attach failed for volume, rpc error: code = Internal desc = Could not attach volume, error listing AWS instances:
After updating our EKS Kubernetes to versions 1.29 mongodb went on pending state, stop working.
See below
NAME                           READY   STATUS              RESTARTS   AGE
api-gateway-768d8b8cc6-f7swz   1/1     Running             0          8h
authapi-cfb964777-gnjvz        1/1     Running             0          8h
basketapi-7cbb86fc75-2xq2h     1/1     Running             0          8h
mongo-6749cf47f6-54ddw         0/1     ContainerCreating   0          4h17m
mongo-78764f686f-vgvtg         0/1     ContainerCreating   0          36m
packageapi-56854f7dbf-zqn4f    1/1     Running             0          8h
providerapi-7c78ddb486-m9bcf   1/1     Running             0          8h
serviceapi-6877d9b6b4-t4ggz    1/1     Running             0          8h
userapi-f5b8c64f4-gw565        1/1     Running             0          8h
pedropaulino@Pedros-Air \~ %

Below is the full error message

AttachVolume.Attach failed for volume "pvc-" : rpc error: code = Internal desc = Could not attach volume "vol-" to node "i-": error listing AWS instances: operation error EC2: DescribeInstances, get identity: get credentials: failed to refresh cached credentials, failed to retrieve credentials, operation error STS: AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity, failed to get rate limit token, retry quota exceeded, 0 available, 5 requested

More error message in details:
kubectl get event  
LAST SEEN   TYPE      REASON               OBJECT                       MESSAGE
92s         Warning   FailedAttachVolume   pod/mongo-6749cf47f6-54ddw   AttachVolume.Attach failed for volume "pvc-38e6ea4c-6d63-46a8-8b0f-0ccc74c05e8c" : rpc error: code = Internal desc = Could not attach volume "vol-08a4fca2489e3cef8" to node "i-09b9b0fde432495b9": error listing AWS instances: operation error EC2: DescribeInstances, get identity: get credentials: failed to refresh cached credentials, failed to retrieve credentials, operation error STS: AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity, failed to get rate limit token, retry quota exceeded, 0 available, 5 requested
92s         Warning   FailedAttachVolume   pod/mongo-78764f686f-vgvtg   AttachVolume.Attach failed for volume "pvc-38e6ea4c-6d63-46a8-8b0f-0ccc74c05e8c" : rpc error: code = Internal desc = Could not attach volume "vol-08a4fca2489e3cef8" to node "i-09b9b0fde432495b9": error listing AWS instances: operation error EC2: DescribeInstances, get identity: get credentials: failed to refresh cached credentials, failed to retrieve credentials, operation error STS: AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity, failed to get rate limit token, retry quota exceeded, 0 available, 5 requested

I have tried a few things but no success.
